# Capture Session timeout on Server side in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I need to do something on **Session End** Event.
How can I access this event?
anything similar to this event maybe timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to handle this in `ASP.NET Core` - on page load on client side (in `JS` code) to schedule the timer for session timeout and warn the user when it's close to expire. If user responds - ping server side (to refresh the session), or redirect the user to logout page. Your session timeout can be configured in `Startup` class. So you need to pass the same value to client view, setup a timer (let say it is 20 minutes) to show the modal after 19 minutes to the user with counting down timer for a minute and a button like "Stay Online". When the user clicks the button - do `AJAX` call to server side (some `Ping` action in your `Home` controller, or something like that).

Comment: That's what I was thinking about, but I was trying to find another better way.

It's already working. @Dmitry

Comment: Yes, I was trying to find a better approach either :) But I didn't find it for `ASP.NET Core`

Comment: You cannot necessarily count on JS being available or enabled. It's fine if you're just wanting to add progressive enhancement, like helpfully letting the user know their session is about to expire in the middle of filling out a multi-step form. However, you cannot *rely* on this to handle something that always must be done.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes, we cannot reply on it. The worst case (with JS disabled) will be a redirect to login page on user's attempt to do anything after session expiration.

Answer (score 7):

ASP.NET has a `Session_OnEnd` event you could register in Global.asax, but even then it was highly unreliable: you could only use it with in-proc sessions and it could only monitor the session expiration, not when a user does something like close the browser window.

ASP.NET Core has nothing similar, though, mostly because it really doesn't make sense to. More than anything, ASP.NET Core is designed for scale, something in-proc *anything* is the antithesis of. Session store is distributed by default. Even when you do use in-memory sessions, it's still using an implementation of `IDistributedCache`. Having a distributed session store makes monitoring expirations untenable, so such functionality has not been added.

More to the point, sessions are not actively expired. Instead, it's when the user next sends back the session cookie, after allowing the session to expire, that the session is destroyed and a new session created. Also sessions employ sliding expirations, so as long as the user remains active within the timeout window, the session will effectively never expire.

Long and short, what you're looking for is not possible. However, this does sort of scream XY problem. You've got some sort of problem you need to solve (X), and you've decided the way to solve it is to do something on session expiration (Y). However, you can't figure out how to do Y, either, so you're asking a question about Y, when you should really be asking about X. I would suggest creating a new question about the *actual* problem you need to solve; there's likely a better way.

Comment: Actual problem: We want to log when a session ends for a user that is adding a course. We only allow 70 minutes session timeout for them to attach .PDF documents. Actual solution: This avoids malicious activity all day and night. If the session time's out and they have not clicked on "I am finished" or "I don't need to add documents" then we need to know what happened. Capturing the timeout event for specific user lets us know they shut the browser down or waited too long.