# ASP.NET Core Session End Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the normal traditional ASP.Net we have the Session.OnStart() and OnEnd() event to perform any operation like saving the data to the database before timeout.

In the similar lines, do we have anything in the ASP.Net core.

I want to save the data into database before the session is timed out.

In my startup.cs,

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.Name = "SalesQdata";                
            });
```

But how to write the session event to perform my data save to database operation

Can anyone please help me over here

Comment: It seems asp.net core does not support it.See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/20).Have you ever seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190635/capture-session-timeout-on-server-side-in-asp-net-core-2-1) to do it in client-side?