# How do you run custom code when Session timeout expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

in my **Startup.cs** I have the following code to kill the session after the time span has been reached of 30 minutes.

```
services.AddSession(options => {
     options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); //Session Timeout.
});
```

what I am trying to achieve in my Startup.cs is that I want to include some sort of `bool TimeExpired = true;` when session expired and add the following code to update my database:

```
if(TimedExpired)
{ 
     RecordsContext oContext = new RecordsContext(); 
     List<Users> lUsers = oContext.Users.ToList();
     for(int i = 0; i < lUsers.Count; i++)
     {
          if(lUsers[i].usernameid == HttpContext.Session.GetString("usernameid")
          {
               lUsers[i].IsUserLoggedIn = false;
               oContext.SaveChanges();
               break;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you running in IIS?  If so it's probably better to do it from there.  The default `AppPool` timeout is 20 minutes.  Also, it's probably not a good idea to hang onto a EF context for 30 minutes before saving changes.  Apart from possible data loss, it limits the scalability of your system

Comment: it's all ready been coded that way and it's working when the session expires and yes I am running it in IIS (working fine). That's been said i'm trying to add that statement. thanks

Comment: note sure if I am at the right track: 

TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.Minute();
            TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                //If you type 1 to 59 minutes Captcha will work
                options.IdleTimeout = end;
            });
            if (now < end)
            {
                
            }

Comment: Possible duplicate of _[ASP.NET Core Session End Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923541/asp-net-core-session-end-event)_.  Also see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/20).  Not good news I'm afraid