# Capturing idle timed-out user details in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have set the idle timeout for users in my application to 16 minutes with the line *options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(960);* in the file *Startup.cs*. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1.

When an idle user has been timed out, I want to automatically redirect all the pages of this user to the login page (with signalR). For this I want to capture the specific user (ID/name) that has reached the idle timeout.

How would I capture the user details of the timed out user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923541/asp-net-core-session-end-event

Comment: Seems like what I want is not possible after reading the comment of that question. I probably have to create custom middleware to track user activity and implement my own idle timeout system.