# Using SqlCommand inside of AddSession in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was trying to execute a `SqlCommand` after the `TimeSpan` ends. When the `IdleTimeout` has been called, the user would go into the `homepage` and need to login again. But in addition. I want to call a command for my `Last Login`:

```js
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = true;
                options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            });
}
```

I would like to add a `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` inside of this part of the code:

```js
services.AddSession(options =>
{
   options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
});
```

I tried many things inside of it, after debugging. When the user logged in it will start the `AddSession` and I thought it will only execute when the TimeSpan ends. Where can I put the end of the command after Timespan ends?

Here's my scenario:

- When User logs in, `AddSession` starts
- When the user idled for 10 mins, it will execute the `SqlCommand` with last login
- After executing the last login will update into new DateTime

Comment: Your title mentions `asp.net` but your tag is `asp.net-core`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Ah its core, and I found a solution about it, I used a jquery function

Comment: It's been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923541/asp-net-core-session-end-event) - just a comment though, no answers

Comment: When the user closed the browser or lost connection, jquery won't help. Be sure to handle that

Comment: Yeah, I maximized my timespan into `FromDays(30)` then let my `SqlCommands` to handle the logout buttons and backbuttons

Comment: Just save the last login time as soon as the user logs in, and then again whenever the user refreshes the session. So the timeout is simply `lastlogintime + 10 minutes`